# ServerSockets accepts corretly but not receive any data

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I'm having a little problem (I don't understand why, in other apps it works fine) with a server-client pair:

Client Side

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, 3307)) { // the host variable is written previously
    try {
        socket.getOutputStream().write(150);
        socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PACSFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Server Side:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3307);
        Socket s = ss.accept();    //Accepts the connection without trouble;
        final String num = "" + s.getInputStream().read();  //The debugger stop after here!

        System.out.println(num);  //Never executed, why?

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Imagea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try building a `PrintWriter` on top of the `OutputStream`, and use `PrintWriter#println(150)` and then `PrintWriter#flush()`. I can't give a reason, but i have seen it work :D

Comment: The problem is that i'm not going to send only numbers, this is a test.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me.

Comment: it must work for everybody but... I don't understand this.

Comment: Now works. Thank you everybody. Close the question.